# Restrict acces in DTO class for fields and return different value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm implementing authorization in my Spring Boot application. And I want to apply authorization to dto's.

See the class below

```
public class ExampleDTO{
    private String phoneNumber; // want to restrict acces on this field.
}
```

E.g.

User A with permission A can see phoneNumber 123456789
User B with permission B can see phoneNumber 123456***

A solutions can be something like this:

```
public void setPhoneNumber(String iban) {
    if (Service.checkPermission("A")) {
        this.phoneNumber= 123456789;
    } else if (Service.checkPermission("B")) {
        this.phoneNumber= "123456***";
    } else {
        this.phoneNumber= "*********";
    }
}
```

But this is against the OOP principle.

Also I can do this in a service:

```
public ExampleDTO getExampleDto(String iban) {
    if (checkPermission("A")) {
        return ExampleDtoA;
    } else if (checkPermission("B")) {
        return ExampleDtoB;
    } else {
        return ExampleDtoC;
    }
}
```

But this will allow code duplication;

So does one of you have a better solution?

Comment: Are you using spring data? You could create different DTOs for different types of users/roles. Check the documentation chapter about  projections : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go is to use a builder to build ExampleDto. Something like this:

```
public class ExampleDTOBuilder {

    public enum PhonePermission { A, B, NONE };
    
    private String phoneNumber;
    private PhonePermission phonePermission = PhonePermission.NONE;
    
    public ExampleDTOBuilder setPhoneNumber( String phoneNumber ) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        return this;
    }
    
    public ExampleDTOBuilder setPermission(PhonePermission phonePermission) {
        this.phonePermission = phonePermission;
        return this;
    }
    
    public ExampleDTO build() {
        ExampleDTO dto = new ExampleDTO();
        
        switch (this.phonePermission) {
        case A:
            dto.setPhoneNumber(this.phoneNumber);
            break;
        case B:
            dto.setPhoneNumber(getMaskedPhoneNumber(this.phoneNumber));
        default:
            dto.setPhoneNumber("********");
            break;
        }
        
        return dto;
    }
    
    private String getMaskedPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        return "123***"; // do your masking
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
ExampleDTO dto = new ExampleDTOBuilder()
        .setPermission(PhonePermission.A)
        .setPhoneNumber("123456")
        .build();
```

More details about the Builder pattern can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are saving these phone numbers in a database and that you want to persist the real phone numbers, but return different values based on permissions.

If this is the case, then you should not alter the `setPhoneNumber` method of the DTO as this could put the following phone number values into your DB: `123456***`, `*********`.

You can encapsulate the logic in a converter between your entity and dto layer

```java
public class ExampleService {
    ExampleDto getExample(String iban) {
        // Get entity from your DB
        ExampleEntity entity = entityRepository.getEntity(iban);
        return converter.convert(entity);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Converter {
    public ExampleDto convert(ExampleEntity entity) {
        ExampleDto dto = new ExampleDto();
        if (checkPermission("A"))
            dto.setPhoneNumber(entity.getPhoneNumber());
        else if (checkPermission("B"))
            dto.setPhoneNumber(entity.getPhoneNumberPartialMasked();
        else
            dto.setPhoneNumber(entity.getPhoneNumberMasked());
        return dto;
    }
}
```

If you are using the spring framework, then you can see the following classes: `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` and `org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService`. There are lots of examples out there on how to use these.